# GearmanManager Installation

Tags: gearman

I am new to ubuntu and am trying to install gearmanmanager for gearman.

I have downloaded gearmanmanager tar.gz from this location: https://github.com/brianlmoon/Gearma...tarball/master

While trying to install it through install.sh, I got the following error.

> Error: Detecting linux distro as redhat- or debian-compatible Which
>   PHP library to use, pecl/gearman or PEAR::Net_Gearman? install.sh: 55:
>   select: not found install.sh: 57: Syntax error: "done" unexpected

Please someone guide me in right path to get rid of this error.

Answer (score 0):

The install.sh is only for redhat and debian builds. I don't think it will work on Ubuntu. That was a contribution and I did not make it. It's not that hard to get it going yourself. You just need to put either pecl-manager.php or pear-manager.php in your path and create a config.ini file to pass to the one you are going to use.